# Is there a R technique that creates connection to data file instead of loading it in memory

Tags: r

R currently loads all the data in the memory and works from there. While this is a useful behavior to allow multiple users to work on the same file. It is painful if the data file is larger than the system's memory(RAM). My system's memory is 24gb and my CSV data file size is 30gb. I have tried importing in chunks and the overall analysis is still frustrating and painful.

Is there a R package or technique that creates a connection to the datafile(csv; excel; delimited etc)? I don't mind if that locks that data file for other users while that particular datafile is in use. This kind of behavior is present in SAS and working with big data files is so much easier with libname statement. I see R's overall analytical advantage but loading of big data files is really a big issue.

If R experts here could share their experiences on how to load big data files(larger than system's RAM) into R with or without package that would be great. So far, I have tried data.table; readr; ff; bigmemory and importing the file in chunks, didn't try RHadoop because I am working from my personal computer and not from hadoop distributed environment-happy to give it a shot as well. All of them seem to depend on system's RAM. Is there a way to bypass R's dependency on system's RAM? I think this discussion will help R users to handle big data(bigger than system memory more efficiently) as we learn from our collective sharing of experiences.

Comment: This may not answer your question, but data.table is a good alternative to data.frame in terms of memory. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/05/data-table-data-frame-work-large-data-sets/

Comment: I have used data.table but that still is limited by system's RAM.

Comment: The CRAN Task View on [High Performance Computing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) has a section on Large Memory and Out-of-Memory Data, notably the `ff` and `bigmemory` packages. There's also, of course, the potential for other backends - connecting to databases, Hadoop, Spark, etc., most all of which have packages to facilitate the interface.

Comment: Do you have control over the file format? There are other formats that allege partial-loads. SQLite might work, too.

Comment: Changing the file format is good idea. I will give that a shot as well.